# Duplicates In DataTable, Getting Last By Specifying Two Properties

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable, with two columns of type `String` named `ID` and `Value`. These values are not required to be unique.

As I add to my DataTable throughout my application, at some point I am trying to get the last item that was added that meets the value of the two properties. For example, for all records where `ID = 1` and `Value = 2`, there may be several. I need the last record.

I have been trying to use LINQ groupbys, the `MyDataTable` variable is my datatable.:

```
var groupQuery = from table in MyDataTable.AsEnumerable()
group table by new {column1 = table["PERSON_GU"], column2 = table["FIELD"]}
into groupedTable
select new
{
x = groupedTable.Key, // Each Key contains column1 and column2
y = groupedTable.Count()
};
```

I cant figure out how to make this select last though, it appears to return an anonymous type which is a little out of my development skill wheelhouse.

In summary, I have a datatable with two columns, I am trying to group my final datatable by these column values, and then get the last item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last `DataRow` of each group:

```
var groupQuery = 
    from table in MyDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    group table by new {column1 = table["PERSON_GU"], column2 = table["FIELD"]}
    into groupedTable
    select groupedTable.Last();
```